# Importing a Netbeans Swing project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

We were using Netbeans during our class, created a small Swing application. We now have to finish it at home.

But I find Netbeans rather counter-intuitive, like Eclipse a lot more. I tried importing the existing Netbeans project into Eclipse, but then it doesn't want to use it's own WindowBuilder (Swing designer) with the existing code.

Is there any way to use the Eclipse GUI designer with my existing code?

Comment: well i think the best thing to do is complete your design from netbeans and then import the project